google maps E/FrameEvents( 8755): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame
I have implemented google maps (maps SDK for android) in my flutter app to show users on the map which used to work very well without any problems.
However, all of a sudden, the next day I am running my code and while using the maps, I clicked on the marker on the map, which should normally opens a page containing the users from this specific region, but instead it returns null in the console with this message
**E/FrameEvents(19067): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
**
How to fix this????
I tried changing the API key in my android manifest, but it didn't work either.

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read How To Ask to improve your chances of getting help. Please also put a minimal reproducible code so that the community can help you better.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

That is how I did:
// Solved the 'updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame' error by disabling MyLocation layer
myLocationEnabled: false,

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
